# How to iterate over a array of hash in serializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, active-model-serializers

I have a grouped collection and I want to serialize it but it returns me with an error 'undefined method `read_attribute_for_serialization' for # '. This is my sample data without serializer:

```
{
    "message": "success",
    "data": {
        "reports": {
            "export": [
                {
                    "name": "Order",
                    "report_type": "export",
                    "parameters": "\"{order_date: '10-10-2019'}\"",

                },
                {
                    "name": "Order",
                    "report_type": "export",
                    "parameters": "\"{order_date: '10-10-2019'}\"",
                }],
            "import": [
                {
                    "name": "Order",
                    "report_type": "import",
                    "parameters": "\"{order_date: '10-10-2019'}\"",
                },
                {
                    "name": "Order",
                    "report_type": "import",
                    "parameters": "\"{order_date: '10-10-2019'}\"",
                }
            ],
            "details": [
                {
                    "name": "Order",
                    "report_type": "details",
                    "parameters": "\"{order_date: '10-10-2019'}\"",
                },
                {
                    "name": "Order",
                    "report_type": "details",
                    "parameters": "\"{order_date: '10-10-2019'}\"",
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

This is my serializer:

```
class ReportSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :report_type, :parameters

  def parameters
    JSON.parse(object.parameters)
  end
end
```

This is my controller code:

```
  def reports_list
    reports = Report.all.group_by(&:report_type)
    render_collection(reports, { name: 'reports' }, each_serializer: ReportSerializer)
  end
```

But return me with an error : `` undefined method `read_attribute_for_serialization' for #<Hash:0x0000562eebbddee8> ``

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: The parameters has is quoted with double quotes around it. You need to remove quotes.

Comment: @AmitPatel Yes but that isn't related to the error she is getting.

Answer (score 2):

`*.group_by()` is an `Enumerable` method which returns Hash - I think render_collection expects to receive `ActiveRecord::Relation` - use `*.group(:report_type)` instead